# How can I switch between branches without reinstalling packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have many different feature branches in my React Native project, some with new packages, so I have to re-run `yarn` whenever I switch between them..

What's the standard JS/node approach for this? If it was python, I'd use virtual env.

Comment: Just run `yarn`. If the packages are in your local Yarn cache, it won't take a long time to link them into place.

Comment: Yeah only 1-2 minutes but it's just a headache to do repeatedly. It makes me hesitant to switch branches

Comment: Well, you can shuffle node_modules trees around too - that'd be something like virtualenvs, I guess.

Comment: If installing the packages takes that long, it might be worth writing a small script for changing branches. All you need is when changing to rename `node_modules` to something like `node_modules_<old_branch_name>` then *if present* change `node_modules_<new_branch_name>` to `node_modules`.

Comment: @VLAZ not bad idea, then just he must also add in the .gitignore something like node_modules_*

Comment: @VLAZ I like this approach, would it be a bash script or what?

Comment: @djangodev could be whatever is available. If you're using Git through Bash, then a Bash script makes the most sense. If you're using in on Windows through PowerShell, you can make a PowerShell script. You can even use JavaScript, if you wish and run it with `node myChangeGitBranchScript.js feature/myFeature` (it can also take parameters). Could be viable multiplatform option. Could also be Python or even Ruby. Whatever is most convenient - the operations are simple enough, it's renaming a directory (up to twice) and running a Git command. Should just be few commands in all cases.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, I usually switch with VScode UI, but I think a node script could work

Comment: Yep, it's not an ideal solution, as it requires working through a script. There might be a way to hook through VSCode but it's also not going to work through other Git managers, e.g., other editors. However, a script is at least a workaround here.